# Screenshot and send to email

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a program at vb.net 8. The program is actually a key logger. I am creating the key logger to track my uncle's son whether he is studying in the internet or playing games. I've made the keystrokes section to send keystrokes to e-mail but only keystrokes cannot help me. I thought whenever my uncle's son press enter, program should capture the screenshot and send to my email. I use `e.key` to scan the enter button but I have no idea how to capture the screenshot. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you made a keylogger, yet you have no idea of taking a "screenshot" of your monitor? Perhaps start reading msdn? and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cf29248c-04d7-42f6-9f0e-381fb994f13f/vbnet-help-with-screen-capture?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: i'm just a beginner on vb.net so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your a beginner "coding" a non-beginner stuff which probably you don't even understand... it just "works", but i already gave you a link where you can find another "working" solution.

Comment: i took large amount of time just to make keylogger and it is working, just i have no idea how to do a screenshot, anyways, thanks for your help

Comment: lots of games can be played mainly with mouseclicks. screenshots every X mins stored to some secret folder with a contact sheet of thumbnails sent to uncle would work better.  logging internet destinations would probably be even more effective and easier

Comment: yes that is also one idea but uncle is 0 at computer knowledge!

Comment: I bet he can distinguish Dragons and Porn from MAth and Spelling

Comment: he can definitely do that but your second idea(logging internet destinations) does not work in this case!

Comment: How old is your cousin?

Answer (score 0):

You should locate the value for the ENTER button.

Key Values: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html

Then declare a function that performs/takes the screenshot and and returns the screenshot to the e-mail of yours, should be *.ToString. Make sure your function has a string declaration between the brackets.

Hope this helps you!